# Collectors.summingLong or mapToLong to summarize long values

Tags: java, java-8

I've got a list of objects with a value and want to summarise all these values. What is the preferred way to do this in Java 8?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<AnObject> longs = new ArrayList<AnObject>();
    longs.add(new AnObject());
    longs.add(new AnObject());
    longs.add(new AnObject());

    long mappedSum = longs.stream().mapToLong(AnObject::getVal).sum();
    long collectedSum = longs.stream().collect(Collectors.summingLong(AnObject::getVal));

    System.out.println(mappedSum);
    System.out.println(collectedSum);
}

private static class AnObject {
    private long val = 10;

    public long getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

I think mapToLong is more straight forward but I can't really motivate why.

*Edit: I've updated the question by changing from summarizeLong to summingLong, that's why some answers and comments might seem a bit off.*

Comment: with mapToLong there is one method call fewer I suppose

Comment: I agree that `mapToLong` version is more clear.  On a side note, you can use `Collectors.summingLong(...)` instead of `summarizingLong(...)` if all you care about is the sum.

Comment: @softarn did you find a elegant way of doing it? I have a similar situation with an additional requirement where I need to find the length of getValue and then sum it up.

Answer (score 5):

I think using `Collectors.summarizingLong(AnObject::getVal))` would do more work than you need it to do, as it computes other statistics beside the sum (average, count, min, max, ...).

If you just need the `sum`, use the simpler and more efficient method :

```
long mappedSum = longs.stream().mapToLong(AnObject::getVal).sum();
```

After you changed `Collectors.summarizingLong` to `Collectors.summingLong`, it's hard to say which option would be more efficient. The first option has an extra step (`mapToLong`), but I'm not sure how much difference that would make, since the second option does more work in `collect` compared to what the first option does in `sum`.

Comment: I don't think it computes this statistics until you need it? Don't know for a fact, just sounds reasonable.

Comment: @softarn based on the Javadoc, it computes everything - `summarizingLong ... Returns a Collector which applies an long-producing mapping function to each input element, and returns summary statistics for the resulting values`. Once you apply that Collector on your Stream, it computes all the statistics, regardless of the method you access later.

Comment: It’s *the* feature of streams that what looks like an “extra step” is just a part of the overall operation it will eventually perform. So it’s not really a difference.